# Large InnoDB data size even though entire database is MyISAM?

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I'm running `mysqltuner` to tune up my database and I'm running into a very strange occurrence.

Even though the entire database is MyISAM (all tables) it says the following:

```
[!!] InnoDB data size / buffer pool: 403.1M/128.0M
```

The default storage engine of the database was InnoDB (even though all tables are MyISAM) so I thought that might be causing the problem somehow but when I changed the default-storage-engine value to MyISAM I still see the same exact InnoDB-related warning in mysqltuner.

So why is this happening and how do I fix it? I'd rather not waste 400M on InnoDB's buffer pool when I'm not using InnoDB to begin with.

Note: What I am NOT trying to do here is discuss the age-old question of MyISAM VS InnoDB, I just need to figure out why InnoDB is eating my resources even though I'm not using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InnoDB uses only 128.0M of memory, the rest is read without buffer when needed. This won't cause any problems. MySQL won't use buffer/cache parts for InnoDB without need, so, if you don't have anything in InnoDB format - you have nothing to worry about.

You can competely disable InnoDB with by adding `skip-innodb` in `my.cnf` in section `[mysqld]`.

Comment: Well, actually, I was being stupid, and information_schema tables are InnoDB. I was only checking my own tables. Now, do you think I should do what mysqltuner says and increase the InnoDB buffer pool? Is it important for performance?

Comment: No, it, won't affect anything - these tables are for information needs (MEMORY).